# How to handle kafka producer and database save transaction?

Tags: spring, postgresql, apache-kafka

I need to send an object to a kafka topic, and then only save it to the postgres db if the publishing to the topic was successful, how can do this please ?

Comment: Can you please be more specific? The question is too broad to give meaningful help.

Comment: This is a solved problem using different tools... I.e. You should really consider using Kafka Connect JDBC sink rather than write this yourself

Answer (score 0):

You can make the producer synchronous.

```java
@Autowired
private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

@Transactional
public void sendMessage(String msg) {
    kafkaTemplate.send(topicName, msg).get();
    saveToDb(msg);
}
```

Or you can add a callback

```java
public void sendMessage(String message) {
            
    ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future = 
      kafkaTemplate.send(topicName, message);
    
    future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, String>>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, String> result) {
            saveToDb();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
            
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: if `saveToDb` fails to execute, the event was already sent to kafka so it will not work as exepcted.